# A problem occurred evaluating project ':spring-boot-learn'. > Project with path ':spring-boot-starter-web' could not be found i

Tags: spring-boot

This is the spring-boot source code project that I learn, I want import the local spring-boot-starter-web project to my project, but I get an error, here is my build.gradle and the error message

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.springframework.boot'
version = '3.1.8-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation project(':spring-boot-starter-web')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':spring-boot-learn'.
> Project with path ':spring-boot-starter-web' could not be found in project ':spring-boot-learn'.
```

Big guys, help me, thanks(Minimum 20 characters I thank you)

Comment: Post your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a `-SNAPSHOT` version, but only the `mavenCentral` repository. Spring Boot snapshot versions are not published to Maven Central.

Change the version to a released version like 3.1.7.

Comment: Thank you very much, cool guy, I use the local springboot source code, I don't use the springboot remote repository, is it related to this, I'm not very familiar with gradle, I use Maven a lot, I don't know if it's a problem elsewhere

Comment: To use a locally-built version of Spring Boot that has been published to `$HOME/.m2/repository`, add the line `mavenLocal()` before `mavenCentral()` in the `repositories` block of your build file.